# What mysql command makes all data inaccessable?

Tags: mysql

My database is periodicly being "deleted" by an automated command from the server (because the table is too big). What happens is that all data in a certain table becomes unaccessable with e.g. select. But if I do a "repair" on the table, all data comes back. I would like to stop this nonesense, but I can't find the command that does this. Any help?

Edit: I should note that the DB is on an external machine that I do not have access to.

I have now tried to do a "select" when the db was in this curious state. The table says it has 0 entries, but take 2.5 gb of storrage space. When I selected all I got one tuple, no errors.

Comment: How big is too big? maybe you should revisit the design of your tables. instead of deleting, archive ur data

Comment: In such cases, what is the error you get when trying to select data?

Comment: I dont get any errors, the data is just "gone", but comes back when I do repair. The table is some 2gb big.

Comment: @Cort3z: are you certain a select query returns a valid empty set and doesn't return an error?

Comment: What kind of filesystem / OS are you on?  And is your architecture 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @Jon Cram: I can not explicitly say "yes" right now, since the problem isn't present right now, but when it happens again I will double check. What I do know is that a "Count(*) from myTable" returns 0, and not error (this I am sure of).

Comment: @Chris Henry: I believe it is a linux server, but I do not know for sure. My guess is that it is a 64 bit machine since it is an enterprise-class server.

Comment: Enterprise doesn't mean much. Try doing a `uname -a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its likely your DB is becoming corrupt somehow. There's no command that does that (I hope).

Comment: I dubt it since this happens at a regular basis and I did not make any changes to the DB between two occurances of this issue.

Comment: is the mysql process crashing?

Comment: Not that I can see. Is there a way to get the history out?

Comment: Examine your log files. MySQL itself should be logging its actions as should your OS.

Comment: I dont have access to the os. It is on an external machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and alter each and every one of your tables so they use the [InnoDB engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) instead of MyISAM. It's still be MySQL, but it'll be a lot less prone to data corruption.

And if changing DB altogether is an option, look into using [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/index.html) instead.

Comment: InnoDB does not support fulltext indexing, thus I can not use it.

Comment: In that case there isn't much you can do... MyISAM is very prone to data corruption unless run on top of a fully journaled filesystem.